# Does the order of elements define their place in a CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The following code works as expected: the cells are filled with colors between defined lines

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 4/7;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

I then tried to swap the last two elements (yellow and blue), by swapping the `grid-column` entries:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 4/7;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

`item3` is not correctly displayed. I suppose that this is because `item2` has been rendered further in the grid and the earlier element cannot be rendered anymore (wild guessing).

**I am lost at how the order of the elements in the HTML is influenced by the placement of elements in the CSS, as explained [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)? Shouldn't the order in the HTML be insignificant?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items are inserted one by one into the grid in the order of appearance in the html and according to their specified placement. [The placement algorithm](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-placement-algo) does not try to fill any previous gaps.

> Note: By default, the auto-placement algorithm looks linearly through the grid without backtracking; if it has to skip some empty spaces to place a larger item, it will not return to fill those spaces. To change this behavior, specify the dense keyword in grid-auto-flow.

[image: One item is placed into the second row]

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 4/7;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

#item4 {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 5/6;
}

#item5 {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 1/7;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
  <div id="item4"></div>
  <div id="item5"></div>
</div>
```

In your example you could either make use of the [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) property and set it to `dense` as suggested by the documentation:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 4/7;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

or you could make use of the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to get the wished result:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 4/7;
  order: 3;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

or, as suggested by GCyrillus, force the third item to be placed in the first row by using the [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) property:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 4/7;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The key thing which helped me to understand is that there is no backfill (except if `dense`is used) and therefore grid tries to fill the next available position (column-wise), which means that it is done on row two - which I did not display.